# Trying to find a way to speed up this powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have this script that works fine (output looks good), but it is taking longer than 12 hours now. There are 34220 records in the csv and it's only now on 2110. Maybe I need to load up all the user data first, then compare to the csv file? Thx for help...

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

$CCure = Import-csv C:\Scripts\CCure\CCure-Personnel-enabled.csv 

ForEach ($Row in $CCure) {
    [string]$ID = $Row.ObjectID
    [string]$Name = $Row.Name
    [string]$EmpID = $Row.Int5

    If ($EmpID.Trim() -ne "0") {
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(&(&(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))))((employeeId=*$EmpID))" -SearchBase 'DC=Enterprise,DC=mycompany,DC=org' -Properties SamAccountName,DisplayName,EmployeeId,enabled  | 
    Select @{Name="CCure ObjectID";Expression={$ID}},SamAccountName,DisplayName,@{Name="CCure Name";Expression={$Name}},EmployeeId,@{Name="CCure Int5 Row";Expression={$EmpID}},enabled | Export-csv c:\scripts\ccure\EmployeeIds4-10-2016.csv -NoTypeInformation -append

    }
    }
```

Comment: How many accounts are in the domain?

Comment: Over 21k active users in AD, but CCure likely has many that are not in AD.

Comment: Why do you prepend the `$EmpID` with `*` in the LDAPFilter ? Does the `EmployeeId` contain *more* than just the ID?

Comment: That's a good question. I may have done that from another script and just kept it by accident. I probably could remove that but not sure it would speed things up?

Comment: A search that satisfies `(&(attribute=*value))` is *way* faster (and much less resource intensive on the DC) than one that satisfies `(&(attribute=value))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe I need to load up all the user data first, then compare to the csv file?

That's *exactly* what you need to do!

Since you want to correlate the users in the CSV by the `EmployeeId` attribute, I'd recommend pulling out all the (enabled) users that have the `EmployeeId` populated, and then store them in a hashtable where the `EmployeeId` is used as the key:

```
$ADUserTable = @{}
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)(employeeId=*))' -SearchBase 'DC=Enterprise,DC=mycompany,DC=org' -Properties SamAccountName,DisplayName,EmployeeId |ForEach-Object {
    $ADUserTable[$_.EmployeeId] = $_
}
```

Then, as you iterate over the rows in the CSV, lookup the user in the hashtable instead of searching AD again:

```
$ExistingUsers = ForEach ($Row in $CCure) {
    # Import-Csv always creates string properties anyways
    $ID = $Row.ObjectID
    $Name = $Row.Name
    $EmpID = $Row.Int5.Trim()

    if ($EmpID -ne "0" -and $ADUserTable.ContainsKeys($EmpID)) 
    {
        $ADUserTable[$EmpID] |Select @{Name="CCure ObjectID";Expression={$ID}},SamAccountName,DisplayName,@{Name="CCure Name";Expression={$Name}},EmployeeId,@{Name="CCure Int5 Row";Expression={$EmpID}}
    }
}
```

Do NOT export them to Csv until AFTER you've collected all the information - otherwise you're opening, writing to and closing the same file 35000 times!

So, at the very end:

```
$ExistingUsers |Export-csv c:\scripts\ccure\EmployeeIds4-10-2016.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will undoubtedly speed up execution of your script

---

Note: I've removed the `Enabled` property from `Get-ADUser` and `Select-Object`. Your LDAP Filter already guarantees that only Enabled users are returned, so I don't really see any value in adding it to the CSV

Comment: Hi Mathias, This looks awesome! But I'm getting an error Method invocation failed because [System.Collections.Hashtable] does not contain a method named 'ContainsKeys'.
At line:18 char:9
+     if ($EmpID -ne "0" -and $ADUserTable.ContainsKeys($EmpID))
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Sorry, wrote it by hand, method name is ContainsKey (no s at the end)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, but after all of this, the output only contains 5266 matches? Ugh, this is very dirty data in that system. Now I'll have to figure out another way to validate who exists in both systems as this method appears to be lacking. I will try this with DisplayName next. Thanks again!

Comment: If(@($ADUserTable.Keys -like "*$Email").Count -gt 0) instead of ContainsKey would yield partial matches if that's the problem

Comment: Without getting a sample of the CSV and a few corresponding users from your Active Directory, it's very hard for me to say whether DisplayName/Firstname Lastname/EmployeeId is the best key value for correlation between your data. It basically boils down to: "Do we have any two *distinct* values that are easily comparable between the two data sources?", and then apply the algorithm I've shown you: read both into memory, sort/organize one by keys and then iterate across the other. Makes sense?